# Form is not passing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am developing a rails application.
A very weird problem is driving me crazy.

A form(method is get) is not passing paramters.
It happens only on development mode.
It happens with all browsers.
I tested it with a simple mocking view but the same problem happens.
The log shows that the parameters were not passed.

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.by_store_id(params[:store_id]).by_keyword(params[:keyword]).include_inactive(params[:include_inactive]).order("manufacturer_part_no").paginate :per_page => 50, :page => params[:page]
  end
end

[View]
          = form_tag({:action => :index}, :method => 'get') do
            Store
            = select_tag :store_id, options_for_select(Store.order("id").map { |i| [i.name, i.id]}.unshift([nil, nil]), params[:store_id].to_i)
            %br
            Title/Item No. 
            = text_field_tag :keyword, params[:keyword]
            %br
            = check_box_tag :include_inactive, '1', (params[:include_inactive].to_i == 1)
            Include Ended Items
            %br
            = submit_tag "Find"
```

What do you think is causing the problem?

Thanks.

Sam

I found out what caused the problem:

There is a directory - public/items on my development server and the directory is not in the git.

```
%p This doesn't work!
= form_tag("/items", :method => 'get') do
  = text_field_tag :data, params[:data]
  = submit_tag "Submit"

%p This works.
= form_tag("/items/", :method => 'get') do
  = text_field_tag :data, params[:data]
  = submit_tag "Submit"
```

In such a case, a training slash makes a difference.

Comment: Many things can be happening. Can you show your code?

Comment: If the method is GET you should see the parameters on your URL's query string, e.g.: `http://localhost:3000/app/controller/action?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=v3...&pn=vn`

Comment: I added the related codes. I am not sure this will help. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks.

Comment: I think it would help if you posted the generated HTML